# Django TypeError using TextField bounding the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to create a simple wiki page, which is comprised of several entries.
But have an error **TypeError at /addentry
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'**

The main thing here is entry model. 
Here is part of my **models.py:**

```
class wikies(models.Model):
    num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField()
```

And here is part of my **forms.py:**

```
class entryform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = wikies
        fields = ['num', 'title', 'text']
```

Part of my **template:**

```
        <form action="{% url 'addentry' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> {{entryform.num}} </p>
    <p> {{entryform.title}} </p>
    <p> {{entryform.text}}</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Entry" /></p>
```

This is part of my **views.py**, where I catch the error:

```
def addentry(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    form = entryform(num = request.POST['num'],
                     title = request.POST['title'],
                     text = request.POST['text']
                     )
```

I want to bound the form with values I just get, but have the following error:
*TypeError at /addentry
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'*
Here are POST values:

num

'1.2.3'

text

'Water is very important resource.'

title

'Importance of water'

I've read the docs, I've searched through StackOverflow, but I have no idea what to do. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #views.py 
 def addentry(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
           form = entryform(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               form.save(commit=Fale)
               num = form.cleaned_data['num'],
               title = form.cleaned_data['title'],
               text = form.cleaned_data['text']
               form.save(commit=True)
           return redirect('/')
        else:
             form=entryform()
             return render(request,....,{'form':form})

    #template
    <form action="{% url 'addentry' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```